# Why BitchX is called BitchX?

Tags: history, terminology, irc

I'm curious to know the reason for the name of `BitchX`. I searched on internet for etymology but it was a fail.

Comment: Just to keep decent girls away from dirty IRC areas ! maybe:-)

Comment: Because it's a noun *and* a verb?  "Firefox" is from Mandarin, but that still doesn't explain why the browser is called that.  I would guess because someone involved said "How about firefox?" and other people concerned said, "Ok".  According to wikipedia the original BitchX was *'written by "Trench" and "HappyCrappy"'*, so go figure...

Comment: @goldilocks Well, actually, Firefox has a much more interesting naming history than that, involving at least a few flamewars and trademark threats...

Comment: @derobert : Sounds like the long version of same, lol.  For all history knows, *Trench* had to hold a cigarette to *HappyCrappy*'s forearm until s/he agreed that "ParleyX is dumb name!"

Comment: Only the original author can answer this. It should be closed as opinion based...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I went to #BitchX on [EFnet](http://www.efnet.org/) and asked the question there. People were able to tell me that the original script for [ircII](http://eterna.com.au/ircii/) made by *Trench* and *HappyCrappy* was already called BitchX: A version of their script from late 1995 contains the line

```
assign versionmesg ^BBitchX^B v713 by Trench and Happycrappy
```

They did not know why the original script was called BitchX, though.

Additionally, there are various websites on BitchX made by dedicated users with many tips and tricks on using the client, scripts for BitchX, etc. [One of these websites](http://izzo.stoynev.net/beetch), made by *izzo*, tells us the following story:

> The name comes from "Bitch Cross" - one of Shakespeare's famous historical tragedies, Henry V, where King Henry proclaims, "Blessèd are souls of bitches' cross".
> *([Source](http://izzo.stoynev.net/beetch/main.html))*

So, according to *izzo*, the name would come from [Shakespeare's *Henry V*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_V_(play)). The same claim is made in [this article](http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/BitchX) and in [this forum thread](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1358695-B-i-t-c-h-X-loading-then-kicks-me-out-anyone-experienced-it).

So there's one story... judge for yourself!

I would add that it is also at least as likely that there is no deeper meaning behind the name. BitchX started out as a script for ircII written by two enthusiastic hackers in the mid-90s. Scripts in those days oftentimes had meaningless random names. It may just have been the first thing which came to their mind, and it stuck.

Answer (score 6):

In ["BitchX Tutorial by Ferry Boender"](http://linuxreviews.org/software/irc/bitchx/) I found following:

> BitchX can be a real Bitch to work with.

I concluded from the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Real%20Bitch) definition that it might mean that the BitchX is *classy software that does the right thing no matter what and doesn't care what anyone thinks about that!*

Answer (score 5):

I found this explanation [here](http://linuxreviews.org/dictionary/index.html.en):

> bitchx - The rudest irc client (in many ways). Evil? Use Bitchx.

Also [this wiki page](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitchX):

> BitchX is known for its distinct messages when quitting the program. An example is:
>
> "Khaled uses BitchX. CTCP TROUT THIS, BITCH!"
> Where reference is made to the creator of the competitive program mIRC, Khaled Mardam-Bey. Other reports can be found in /etc/bitchx/BitchX.quit.